# Can connect to the internet when gateway IP settings are in 10.0.0.* scope but not 192.168.0.* scope

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router

My default router settings use 192.168.0.1. All of the devices in my house can connect to the internet and the gateway when the IP range is set to default except for my Ubuntu device. My ubuntu device cannot connect to the gateway at all and intermittently loses connection to the internet.

If I change the IP router settings to the 10.0.0.* range, my Ubuntu device can connect to the gateway and no longer has trouble connecting to the internet.

I have scanned to see if any apps are bound to the IP or port 80/443 but come up with nothing.

One thing that I did notice is that if I disable IPv4, my IPv6 cannot connect to the internet at all. Sorry, I don't have the experience to know whether or not that is relevant.

Comment: What is your question here, the information your giving us is so vague I don't even know how to start to answer it? What router? What the the output of "inxi -Nn" and then the output of "nmcli device show" under each subnet setting change? When you say you can't connect to the gateway, does that mean you can't open the web page or you can't ping 192.168.0.1 or you can't resolve domain names or ?

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done?